# How to finish a springframework ConcurrentTaskScheduler

Tags: java, spring

This is probably an obvious one, but how do I finish a `ConcurrentTaskScheduler` (`org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ConcurrentTaskScheduler`)?  I'm starting them up thusly:

```
readConfig();
makeThreads();

for (HTTPEngineThread thread : threads)
{
    ConcurrentTaskScheduler taskExecutorHTTP = new ConcurrentTaskScheduler();
    taskExecutorHTTP.scheduleAtFixedRate(thread, getFrequency() * 1000);
}
```

and when I shut down `Tomcat` it takes around 30 seconds and I get this:

```
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearReferencesThreads The web application [/mywebapp] appears to have started a thread named [pool-2-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

I'm guessing this is the task scheduler, but I can't find any way to kill it nicely.  My threads themselves don't have any loops, just run methods that gets called once per interval by the scheduler.

EDIT: As requested, here's `HTTPEngineThread` (it doesn't actually do anything yet, other than update a data object with some test data).

```
package com.williamhill.monitoring.statscreen.engines;

import com.williamhill.monitoring.statscreen.query.HTTPQuery;
import com.williamhill.monitoring.statscreen.query.Value;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL; 
public class HTTPEngineThread implements Runnable
{
    private HTTPQuery query;
    private String queryURL;
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("StatsHTTPEngineCatgory");
    private int frequency;
    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public HTTPEngineThread(String queryURL, HTTPQuery query, int frequency)
    {
        this.queryURL = queryURL;
        this.query = query;
        query.add(new Value("Test", 1, 1));
    }

    public void run()
    {
        updateData();
    }

    public void destroy()
    {
    }

    public int getFrequency()
    {
        return this.frequency;
    }

    private void updateData()
    {
        try
        {   
            //Actual work will go here when I've written it (doing an HTTP get)
            query.getValue("Test").update("1");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            log.error("Exception in HTTPEngineThread querying '" + queryURL + "'", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you scheduling yourself and creating task executors yourself. Why not simply let spring handle it, that way they will also be stopped if you shutdown the application.

Comment: I thought that was how it wad done.  I'm totally unfamiliar with this framework, I was just doing it with loops and sleeps originally but someone came and said "here, try this".  How am I supposed to do it?

Comment: Post your `HTTPEngineThread` class.

Comment: Added.  As you can see, it's run method just does a single line, updating the data in one of my objects with the value "1".